# fill string with varying number of replacement field with same variable

Tags: python, string

I have multiple strings that needs to be filled with same variable but varying number of replacement fields in each string

For example

```
var='C'
str1='this is a string with 2 {} {}'
str2='this is  a string with 1 {}'
```

I'm aware that with `format` i have multiple ways to fill string ( pass a keyword arg, a list, or by index...) but i can't find a way to do what I asked.

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to have nested braces?

Comment: no, no nested braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of braces and fill accordingly:

```
var = 'C'
str1 = 'this is a string with 2 {} {}'
str2 = 'this is  a string with 1 {}'


print(str1.format(*tuple(var * str1.count("{"))))
print(str2.format(*tuple(var * str1.count("{"))))
```

**Output**

```
this is a string with 2 C C
this is  a string with 1 C
```

A perhaps better alternative is to use named arguments, as follows:

```
print(str1.replace("{}", "{var}").format(var=var))
print(str2.replace("{}", "{var}").format(var=var))
```